# Retrieve Azure IoT connection string using Python

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub

I have the following code

```py
conn_str = "HostName=my_host.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MY_DEVICE;SharedAccessKey=MY_KEY"
device_conn = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_str)
await device_conn.connect()
```

This works fine, but only because I've manually retrieved this from the IoT hub and pasted it into the code. We are going to have hundreds of these devices, so is there a way to retrieve this connection string programmatically?

It'll be the equivalent of the following

```
az iot hub device-identity connection-string show --device-id MY_DEVICCE --hub-name MY_HUB --subscription ABCD1234
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device id and key are you give to the each device and you choose where to store/how to load it. The connection string is just a concept for easy to get started but it has no meaning in the actual technical level.

You can use `create_from_symmetric_key(symmetric_key, hostname, device_id, **kwargs)` to direct pass key, id and hub uri to sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I found it's not possible to retrieve the actual connection string, but a connection string can be built from the device primary key

```py
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient

# HUB_HOST is YOURHOST.azure-devices.net
# SHARED_ACCESS_KEY is from the registryReadWrite connection string
reg_str = "HostName={0};SharedAccessKeyName=registryReadWrite;SharedAccessKey={1}".format(
        HUB_HOST, SHARED_ACCESS_KEY)

device = IoTHubRegistryManager(reg_str).get_device("MY_DEVICE_ID")
device_key = device.authentication.symmetric_key.primary_key
conn_str = "HostName={0};DeviceId={1};SharedAccessKey={2}".format(
            HUB_HOST, "MY_DEVICE_ID", device_key)

client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(
            conn_str)

client.connect()

# Remaining code here...
```

Comment: This solution requires your devices to have the IoTHub connection string on the device. If your device is compromised this could be a serious security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Other options you could consider include:

- Use the [Device Provisioning service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-dps/) to manage provisioning and connecting your device to your IoT hub. You won't need to generate your connection strings manually in this case.
- Use X.509 certificates (recommended for production environments instead of SAS). Each device has an X.509 cert derived from the root cert in your hub. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-introduction